# how do I add an ajax response to my form without adding a new js file?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this simple submission form and I want to "ajaxify" it so the user isn't redirected to this page **thanks.php** after submission. I want the content from **thanks.php** to respond and show inside the div.

What jquery code will plug right into this to show the response.

```
<div ><form method="post" action="http://domain.com/thanks.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" > &nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" ></form></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give 'form' and 'div' a class or id so it is not so generic, but this should work.

```
$("form").submit(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://{url}/thanks.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {email: $("#email").val()},
        success: function ( data ) {
          $("div").html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```